# Which processes can be launched using performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout function?

Tags: ios-ui-automation

I use UIAutomation to automate an iPad application.  I have tried to use 
(object) performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout(path, args, timeout) to run Safari.app from my script:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var host = target.host();
var result = host.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout("/Applications/Safari.app", ["http://www.google.com"], 30);
UIALogger.logDebug("exitCode: " + result.exitCode);
UIALogger.logDebug("stdout: " + result.stdout);
UIALogger.logDebug("stderr: " + result.stderr);
```

I got the following results:
exitCode: 5
stdout:
stderr:

I’ve also tried to launch echo:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var host = target.host();
var result = host.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout("/bin/echo", ["Hello
World"], 5);
UIALogger.logDebug("exitCode: " + result.exitCode);
UIALogger.logDebug("stdout: " + result.stdout);
UIALogger.logDebug("stderr: " + result.stderr);
```

Results:
exitCode: 0
stdout: Hello World
stderr:

So, looks like performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout works for specific applications only.

Could you please help me to answer the following questions:
1.  What does exitCode = 5 mean?
2.  Which processes can be launched using performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout function?

Answer (score 4):

1) Exit code 5 is most likely EIO, as defined in : Input/Output error. You're attempting to execute "/Applications/Safari.app", which to the launching task is a directory and not a binary.

2) You can launch any application with performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout() that NSTask can launch. As long as it's a valid executable, it should work.

For your specific example though, Safari won't accept an argument passed on the command line like that as a URL to visit. You need to use `open /Applications/Safari.app "http://www.google.com"` instead:

```
var result = host.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout("/usr/bin/open", ["/Applications/Safari.app", "http://www.google.com"], 30);
```

Comment: Does this work on device or are we speaking only about the simulator?

Comment: @Sulthan, host.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout runs a task on the host, not the target.  Simulator/device isn't relevant.